# Can you change the description of a document using Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I currently have a google picker set where you can upload and view files found in the google drive. I would like to be able to call something to change the description of a selected document. I have read the documentation and have found nothing of the sort. I want to change the description because it's an indexable field and am having issues adding custom properties.

If anyone knows a way around this it would be fantastic.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple. Check out updating metadata at https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update

```
var metadata={description: "foo"};
var fileId="1x34sdfeuie764335f34"
http{
 method: "PATCH",
 url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/"+fileId
 data: metadata
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i've read this before but i just don't know how to use this. I just am looking for a small one line example to give me an idea

Comment: JS example pasted above

Comment: The HTTP{ part is returning an error saying unexpected token { any idea why? Btw youre the man thanks so much!

Comment: I just put () around it and it didnt return an error so i believe that fixed it

Comment: whoa - that's a kind of pseudo code. The "http" is just a placeholder for whatever http mechanism you're using eg. Angular's $http, jquery's $ajax, etc. I'm assuming that you know enough JS to do that bit yourself.